# How to mock URIComponentsBuilder in junit

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have this code:

```
UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(baseUrl).queryParam("externalReference", key);
```

if I use below statement in junit:

```
Mockito.when(uriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(ArgumentMatchers.anyString()).queryParam(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(),ArgumentMatchers.any(Object.class))).thenReturn(uriBuilder);
```

I will get exception like: HTTP url cannot be null.

How to mock this in JUnit?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your problem? I have the same question right now where my client class uses UriComponentsBuilder and I'm unable to mock it and test .

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
@Mock
UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder;
@Mock
UriComponents uriComponents;

    Mockito.when(uriComponentsBuilder.path(any())).thenReturn(uriComponentsBuilder);
    Mockito.when(uriComponentsBuilder.buildAndExpand(anyLong())).thenReturn(uriComponents);
```

for the anyLong use the type that you use..