# Mockito URIComponentBuilder mocking

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5

Hi There can anyone help me to mock the UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(oauthURL);
when i am trying to mock by mockito like

```
UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = mock(UriComponentsBuilder.class);
        UriComponents uriComponents = mock(UriComponents.class);
        UriComponents uriComponents1 = uriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://mock.com").build();

Mockito.lenient().when(uriComponentsBuilder.build())
                .thenReturn(uriComponents1);
```

it gives [null] not a valid http url, i tried to give correct url still getting same issue
might be similar to
[How to mock URIComponentsBuilder in junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69312306/how-to-mock-uricomponentsbuilder-in-junit)
but this solution doesn't works.

Comment: Got the answer incase anyone needed, this class has private variables which passsd in the fromHttpUrl method, these private variable needs to mock first using reflection. it Worked!

Comment: Feel free to answer and accept your own question and add the relevant test setup here. This will help upcoming visitors that may struggle with the same issue